# show textfields text in a UITableView using swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm very new in swift programming .
I'm just trying some features of textfield . 
just want to show textfields value in a `UItableView`.
stuck in this code
please check this out ....
and give solution

```
 import UIKit

 class langViewController: UIViewController {
 var txt = ""
 let simpleTableIdentifier = "TableViewCell";
 @IBOutlet weak var txtlang: UITextField!

 @IBOutlet weak var langTableView: UITableView!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
 super.viewDidLoad()

   }

 override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
  super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
   }
 @IBAction func addButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject)
 {
 txt = txtlang.text
  self.langTableView.reloadData()

  langData.append(txt)
  print(langData)
  txtlang.resignFirstResponder()

   }
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView!,                      cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(simpleTableIdentifier) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = txt

    return cell;

 }
```

Comment: Try removing your delagate method from your button handler.

Comment: Please specify the exact problem.

Comment: #flashadvanced i`m not getting you sir

Comment: Mr. Jozsef  i`m just trying to show my textfield value in my textview , im stuck it not giving any error , the code is up there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update your table view cells you have to call `reloadData()`. So you have to do something like this:

**1.** Declare the `txt` variable right where your class definition starts:

```
var txt = ""
```

**2.** In your button handler call `reloadData()` to update your cells.

```
@IBAction func addButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    txt = txtlang.text
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

**3.** Set the text to your cell's label:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(simpleTableIdentifier) as! UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = txt

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: sir, its not working and not giving any error. please help. do i need  to do any changes in my stroryboard.

Comment: Did you put your `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)` method outside `addButtonTapped `?

Comment: right now my code is like                                                                   
  @IBAction func addButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject)
    {
     txt = txtlang.text
    self.langTableView.reloadData()
     langData.append(txt)
    print(langData)
    txtlang.resignFirstResponder()
    } func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(simpleTableIdentifier) as UITableViewCell
 cell.textLabel?.text = txt
  return cell;
   }

Comment: You have to conform to the data source protocol like this: `class langViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource` and then set the dataSource property in `viewDidLoad` like this: `self.langTableView.dataSource = self`

Comment: Dear sir, after changes that you suggest, ` class langViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource ` it  give an error which is " type "langViewController" does not confirm to protocol "UITableViewDataSource" "

Comment: This  happens because you have to implement all required methods of this protocol. You can check them out here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/

Answer (score 0):

thanks #flashadvanced 
i was using a textfield and a tableview 
i trying to get text in tableView from textfield. after suggestion of #flashadvanced i did it.
my code is :

```
class langViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
  var txt = ""
 let simpleTableIdentifier = "TableViewCell";
@IBOutlet weak var txtlang: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var langTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
          self.langTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    self.langTableView.dataSource = self

       }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
       }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return langData.count
}
func  tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:UITableViewCell = self.langTableView
        .dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = langData[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}


@IBAction func addButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject)
{
    txt = txtlang.text


    langData.append(txt)
    print(langData)
    txtlang.resignFirstResponder()
    self.langTableView.reloadData()


}
```